# C# GDI+ can't draw text with spaces

Tags: c#, gdi+

I have some code:

```
string text = "Some text\t with tabs\t  here!";
string spaces = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    spaces += " ";
}

text = text.Replace(@"\t", spaces);
```

I replace all tabs with four spaces and then try to draw text:

```
graphics.DrawString(text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), offsetX, offsetY);
```

But the text draws with only one space between the words. And the other spaces are removed.
How can I draw text with all the spaces?

Comment: The example code is needlessly complex. Why not make a string that contains spaces to begin with. And so remove the call to Replace. Keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: The \t is not being replaced with the spaces when I tested your code, you must be getting \t after replace. Using text = text.Replace("\t", spaces); will replace \t with speaces

Comment: Some (normal) spaces come out very small in some fonts. Some Fonts have larger spaces ([em-spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character)) that may help.. But if you print one with and the same string without spaces on top of each other you will see the spaces..

Comment: Adil, this works: text.Replace(@"\t", spaces); But not this: text.Replace("\t", spaces);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **TextRenderer.DrawText** instead. That's what is used also by Windows.Forms since .NET 2.0, unless UseCompatibleTextRendering is turned on.

```
TextRenderer.DrawText(graphics, text, font,
    new Point(offsetX, offsetY), Color.Black, TextFormatFlags.ExpandTabs);
```

Comment: good suggestion. What is the reasion of e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello World          ", Font, new SolidBrush(SystemColors.ControlText), 20, 100); omit last 10 Space chars? I have to use TextRender.DrawText.

Answer (score 2):

Either both your strings or none of them have to be **verbatim string**. Verbatim string (i.e. @"string") means, *don't apply any interpretations to characters until the next quote character is reached*.

Therefore try this:

```
string text = "Some text\t with tabs\t  here!";
...
text = text.Replace("\t", spaces);
```

Or this:

```
string text = @"Some text\t with tabs\t  here!";
...
text = text.Replace(@"\t", spaces);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your font, some fonts have monospaced (all alphabet has the same space including space) and other doesn't have (every alphabet different space for example "i" has less space than "M"). Please change your font to monospaced font whatever it is.

You see your text seems like has single space because the space in non monospaced font is shorter than in monospaced.

You can read more about [monospaced fonts in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font).